# what Jar's are needed for and ActiveMQ client, application

Tags: jar, jms, classpath, activemq-classic

I have activemq-client-5.13.3.jar on my class path, but i keep getting

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException

If i use activemq-all-5.13.3.jar  on my class path, every thing works.

however I am not allowed to use the  activemq-all  jar.

added jms-api-1.1-rev-1.jar

and now Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/j2ee/statistics/Stats

Comment: http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.8.0/activemq-client/dependencies.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use maven to determine this with the *mvn dependency:tree* command or use other maven centric tools to explore the artifacts dependencies.

At a minimum you would need these for v5.13.3

> slf4j-api.jar geronimo-jms_1.1_spec.jar hawtbuf.jar

Then you can add an slf4j binding like log4j or logback to get proper logs.  There are some others that you might want depending on where / how you are using it like the *geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec jar*.

Of course if you use maven to build you can make this simpler since it will manage the deps for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem with my java application. I needed to insert Spring Boot for rest web service (Jetty Server) and now ActiveMQ for others data exchange.
With

> activemq-client-5.15.11.jar; geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar; geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar; hawtbuf-1.11.jar;

all works.